# How can I restore the app identifier from an app that's in the app store

Tags: ios

Hello I've uploaded an app to app store connect for test flight purposes with an certain identifier. That same identifier recently disappeared from 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' in my apple developer account. I cannot recreate it since its not available, and I think its not available because it's already uploaded to App Store Connect, but it's on the same Developer account so I think I should be able to recreate it?
Is there a way to restore the identifier someway?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question properly. As per your question my suggestions is:

If you are unable recreate identifier, its means identifier being used by some other app. In this case you can't use this identifier.

Comment: I guess you would be right but in fact the app that uses that identifier is also mine. I tried to clarify my question.